# Getting Path to MySQL on Apache running on Windows

Tags: mysql, apache

I've set up an Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.3 server on my Windows 7 machine. However, `phpinfo()` tells me that I have MySQL installed as well, but I had no clue I do. I'm having trouble finding the installation, so how can I find the path to MySQL? I know how to do so with Linux (`whereis MYSQL`), but what do I do with Windows?

Comment: `phpinfo` is just telling you that the MySQL library for PHP is installed. It does not mean MySQL itself is installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you didn't setup MySQL explicitly, and you didn't install a complete WAMP installation, you don't have MySQL. PHP just checks if the MySQL library is installed. If you try to connect, it will probably fail.

Answer (score 0):

- I would check under C:\Program Files\MySql or under c:\MySql
- Also, MySql typically is configured to run on port 3306; so I would
  check whether you have this port open on your local computer. How?
  Just telnet to port 3306 on localhost and see if you can connect. If
  you can, most likely MySQL is running on your PC and you should be
  able to connect to it.
- [Read the MySQL Documentation regarding this topic.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-start-service.html)